# Yahoo cdn confidence + YUI

Tags: yui, yahoo, cdn

I am migrating the javascript of my site to YUI3 and am considering using the YUI files hosted on Yahoo's cdn.

As my site attracts a high amount of traffic I wondered whether anybody had experience of using the cdn and whether there were any problems they experienced or lessons they learnt.

Ideally I would love to offload the bandwidth to Yahoo but am a little concerned that I add a little risk by not being in control.

Any opinon appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is totally rock solid, at least in my experience. The underlying platform is the same cdn that we (flickr) use, as well as all other Yahoo sites.